# Find the nearest markers by connecting to the database

Tags: sql, google-maps-api-3

I have this code to place a marker on the specific coordinates thanks to Google Maps JavaScript v3:

```
function initialize() {
    var gm_latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(59.328615,13.485699);

    var gm_options = {
        zoom: 10,
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 20,
        center: gm_latlong,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        streetViewControl: false
    }

    var gm_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-maps'), gm_options);

    var gm_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: gm_latlong,
        draggable: false,
        map: gm_map
    });
}
```

Very simple! But I want to get the 5 nearest markers for this location and it's here it got complicated - I don't know how to accomplish this! I know that this code only prints one marker and it should be a loop in this function to do such a thing. But I store the coordinates in my database and I want to fetch them from there.

Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you seen the [store locator](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) example in the [Google Maps API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/)?

Comment: I have a [demo](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php) based on the Store Locator This uses PDO instead of mysql_functions which are deprecated

Comment: geocodezip: I haven't but thanks for linking to the page for it on their website :D I'll take a look at it. David: Very nice!